# Time dependent data in the coxph function of survival package

Tags: r, survival-analysis

When considering time dependent data in survival analysis, you have multiple start-stop times for an individual subject with measurements for the covariates as each start-stop time. How does the coxph function keeps track of which subject it is associating the start and stop times along with the covariates?

The function looks as follows

```
coxph(Surv(start, stop, event, type) ~ X)
```

Your data may look as follows

```
subject | start   | stop   | event  | covariate |
--------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
1       | 1       | 7      | 0      | 2         |
1       | 7       | 14     | 0      | 3         |
1       | 14      | 17     | 1      | 6         |
2       | 1       | 7      | 0      | 1         |
2       | 7       | 14     | 0      | 1         |
2       | 14      | 21     | 0      | 2         |
3       | 1       | 3      | 1      | 8         |
```

How can the function get away without an individual subject specifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that survival analysis is not interested in individuals through time, it is looking at total counts for each time point, so the subject specifier is irrelevant. Instead, based on the counts, probabilities can be estimated that any particular subject will be alive/dead at a certain time given certain treatments.

Comment: That last statement is not believed to be true by the survival package's author. He specifically advises that he doesn't know how to construct survival curves when time dependent-covariates are being used.

Comment: @BondedDust I don't understand your comment - there is nothing in this answer about time dependent-covariates... The point is that survival analysis does not consider individuals but proportions and probabilities

Comment: If it doesn't address time-dependent covariates then how can it answer the question? Therneau makes a distinction between what is possible as far as prediction of probabilities with time-dependnent covariates. The question is .... Why don't you?